# add more than 1 video player in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, video-streaming

Is there any way to add more than 1 video player in a single View? I am getting the .m4v list from server adn have to display that much videos in single page.

It doesnot matter if I play 1 video at a time but which ever video I want must play there itself.

So the videos are placed one below other.

I have tried using mpmoviecontroller but it's drawback is it can have only one instance in the whole applicaiton So if i try to alloc 2 players in a view then the first one does not work and only one player works..

Is there any legal alternate way for the same?

Comment: then play videos simultaneously in 2 webviews

Comment: I have no idea how to play a movie in webview. Can you please provide me the way or a little sample? And which controller must be used?

Comment: @sreecharan I have displayed it in webview.. but when I play it it directly opens in full screen mode.. I hae 2 options 1 play/pause and full Screen along woth the videoplayer..

Answer (score 0):

MPMoviePlayerController will allow multiple instances, but only one of them can be playing their movie at any given time.
Please check the link : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html

Comment: I have already checked it.. I have also tried to implement it.. But say I am allocating 3 mpmovieplayercontroller instance then only the last one plays and remaining 2 are not even showing up their controls(play,pause etc..) makin it just a unaccesinle blank Screen.. how to overcome it?

Comment: you can find a step by step procedure [**here**](http://mscerts.programming4.us/programming/ipad%20sdk%20%20%20displaying%20multiple%20videos.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I used `AVPlayer` class (which also `MPMoviePlayerController` uses under the hood) to successfully play multiple videos from multiple source.

The process of using it is more involved than `MPMoviePlayerController`, but I would say it is definitely worth to look at if you want some customized behavior in your player. [The official programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html) is a good start.